# Match nodes of variable depth

Tags: neo4j

I have users who like different geographies (could be a country, state or city) and I want to match those users who like geographies in the same country.

For eg.

```
user A likes USA 
user B likes USA
user C likes San Jose
user D likes France
```

then I want user A to be matched to users B and C.

[image: Node relationships in my graph]

What cypher query will get me the results? This is what I tried:

/** node id of user A is 0 **/

```
START u=node(0) MATCH (u:users) - [:likes] - (g1) - [:contains*0..5] - (g2) - [:likes] - (o:users) RETURN o;
```

This query is not working as expected. What would be a right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, something like [this](https://neo4j-console-20.herokuapp.com/?id=7bvlwi) might work in your case. But pay attention - there might be certain issues in case of circular paths.

The main idea behind this is setting not only relationships but their directions as well.

Comment: I tried this query, but the console just hangs. Could this be due to some circular path issue?

Comment: @Ninja, I won't guess:) Can you share the problematic data sample somehow?